# Regex.Replace is not working

Tags: c#, regex

I'm doing an URL replacer in C# but the Regex.Replace() method is not working. After I click on button1, the text is still the same. Here it is how the code looks like.

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        string t = richTextBox1.Text;
        string URL = textBox1.Text;
        string pattern = @"^(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?$";
        string text = Regex.Replace(t, pattern, URL,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        richTextBox1.Text = text;
    }
```

Comment: what is the `input` and the expected `output`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your regex pattern is bounded by the `^` and `$` anchors, then replacement would only occur when your `t` string consists entirely of a URL only. I assume you want to replace URLs that occur *within* your string; in that case, you just need to remove the anchors:

```
string pattern = @"(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?";
```